# Firestore transaction update multiple documents in a single transaction

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can i update multiple documents in firestore by using a single transaction i searched but i didn't get any answers. Is it possible to update multiple documents in a single transaction? I know it can be done by batch writes.

Comment: Can you prove the structure of your collection, or what you are trying to read/update?

Comment: i am learning firebase by doing sample projects, so i just need to update 2 docs inside a single transaction thats all, any way i found it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured it out we can use multiple ref inside a transaction:

```
var userSuhail = db.collection("users").doc("suhail");
var userSam = db.collection("users").doc("sam");
var userJohn = db.collection("users").doc("john");
var userAlfred = db.collection("users").doc("Alfred");
var userAlfredDetails = db.collection('userdetails').doc('Alfred');

db.runTransaction(function (transaction) {
  return transaction.get(userJohn).then(function (sDoc) {
    var age = sDoc.data().age + 1;
    transaction.set(userAlfred, {
      name: 'Alfred',
      age,
      details: userAlfredDetails,
    });
    transaction.set(userAlfredDetails, {
      address: 'Alfred Villa',
    });
    transaction.update( userJohn   , { age, }, );
    transaction.update( userSuhail , { age, }, );
    transaction.update( userSam    , { age, }, );
    return age;
  });
}).then(function (age) {
  console.log("Age changed to ", age);
}).catch(function (err) {

  console.error(err);
});
```

By the above code the transaction updates age of all users.

Comment: How is this the correct answer? You've not answered your own question :) You asked 'How can I read multiple documents in a single transaction?' and instead your solution shows how to write/update multiple documents after a single read...

Comment: Actual intention was to edit multiple documents inside a transaction, To read multiple documents we can use promise All function
.

Comment: @suhailc But can we read multiple docs in transaction and update each one depending on what was readed?

Comment: @rendom Yes we can read multiple docs inside a transaction, like    
   db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
                return Promise.all([transaction.get(docref1), transaction.get(docref2)]).then((docs) => {   let doc1 = docs[0];
                    let doc2 = docs[1];

Comment: Don't forget that to execute a valid transaction you must do all of your reads first, then based on them do all your writes. You can't do more reads after some writes in the transaction, otherwise you can end up with undefined state.

Comment: @suhailc what if to get the reference of docref2, I need to finish reading docref1 first, hence instead of Promise.all, I used something like:  promise1().then(docref2=>{ promise2(docref2)}) I get Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use batch method which firebase provides. 
This is how I used it to store array of objects, creating multiple documents inside a newly created collection.

```
export const addCollectionAndDocuments = async (collectionKey, objectToAdd) => {
  console.log(collectionKey, objectToAdd);

  let collectionRef = firestore.collection(collectionKey);
  const batch = firestore.batch();
  objectToAdd.forEach(obj => {
    const newDocRef = collectionRef.doc();
    batch.set(newDocRef, obj);
  });
  return await batch.commit();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Proof of concept:

```
var transaction = firestore.runTransaction( t => {
  return t.get(eRef)
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        var employee = doc.data();
        if(employee.status !== 'Off work') {
          t.update(doc.ref, {
            status: 'Off work',
            returnTime: '8 am'
          })
        }
      })
    })
}).then(result => {
  console.log('Transaction success!')
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Transaction failure: ', err)
});
```

Comment: What is eRef here?  It seems like it's a Collection Reference, but Transaction.get only accepts Document References...

Answer (score -6):

Cloud Firestore has a rich set of options for querying collections as the best way to retrieve multiple documents. If your data isn't structured in a way that these queries work, then you need to retrieve the documents one-by-one.  i.e. if your object has a set of keys to other objects, there is no query that works, you need to retrieve them in a loop.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

There is no (current) way to update multiple documents in a single operation with firestore.  There is a batch facility which lets you update multiple documents as a single atomic transaction to ensure data integrity.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

If this doesn't answer your question, please provide more detail on what you are trying to do and the structure of your data.

Comment: what i need is i have 3 documents  1) user 2)project 3)category.  When i add a project it must add the project and also update the count in category and update the project list array in user

Answer (score -8):

you can use this =>

```
firestore.collection("YOUR_COLLECTION_PATH")
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

Also if you want to map the querySnapshot in an array, you can do like this:

```
firestore.collection("YOUR_COLLECTION_PATH")
.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
    var arrayDocs = querySnapshot.docs.map(docData=>docData.data())
    console.log(arrayDocs);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
```

The info is at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: This answer isn't in a transaction which is the point of the original question.