# firestore transactionally update multiple documents in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to transactionally update a User document and a Project document at the same time in python but cannot get it working following the [firestore transactions documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).

I found other documentations like https://stackoverflow.com/a/57653880 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/47546657/23758255 that explains it for other languages, but could not find something for python.

For example, it's not clear to me if I need to create a separate transaction inside `create_project` or have a single transaction object that's initiated at class init time. I tried both, and neither worked.

This is my current code

```
import firebase_admin
import google.cloud
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

class FirestoreApi:
  def __init__(self):
    cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
    self.app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
    self.db = firestore.client()
    self.users = self.db.collection(u'users')
    self.projects = self.db.collection(u'projects')
    self.transaction = self.db.transaction()

  @firestore.async_transactional
  async def create_project(self, user_id: str):
    user_ref = self.users.document(user_id).get(transaction=self.transaction)
    if not user_ref.exists:
      raise Exception(f"User {user_id} not found in database.")
    project_id = create_random_uuid()
    new_project_ref = self.projects.document(project_id)
    project = {
      "id": project_id,
      "userIds": [user_id],
    }
    self.transaction.update(user_ref, {"projectIds": [project_id]})
    self.transaction.set(new_project_ref, project)
    return project

api = FirestoreApi()
project = await api.create_project("robert")
```

The error I get when running the code is

```
.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/async_transaction.py", line 274, in __call__
    (exceptions.Aborted) if not transaction._read_only else ()
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_read_only'
```